# Proof verification: Product of two Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, self-learning

> Let $X, Y$ be Hausdorff spaces. Then $X\times Y$ is a Hausdorff space.

My proof: Let $(x,y)$, $(x',y')$ be distinct points in $X\times Y$. Assume that $x\ne x'$ and $y\ne y'$, then because $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, there exist disjoint neighborhoods $U, U'$ of $x,x'$ and disjoint neighborhoods $V,V'$ of $y,y'$. Then $U\times V$, $U'\times V'$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $(x,y),(x',y')$, so that $X\times Y$ is Hausdorff.

If $x=x'$, then choose disjoint neighborhoods $V,V'$ of $y,y'$. Then $X\times V$, $X\times V'$ are disjoint neighborhoods of $(x,y), (x',y')$. (Symmetrical argument for when $y=y'$.)

Have I missed anything with this proof? I ask because it is simpler than another proof I read.

Comment: You can even skip the first part assuming WLOG that $x\neq x'$ from the beginning.

Comment: @ajotatxe Indeed, if $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ are distinct, then at least one of $x\ne x'$ and $y\ne y'$ is true. So perhaps I could have stated my proof a bit less awkwardly.

Comment: Plot twist: A topological space $T$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta_T = \{(t,t) : t \in T\} \subset T\times T$ is closed. (If you don't already know that, you should prove it, it's instructive and useful.) And $s \colon (X\times X) \times (Y\times Y) \to (X\times Y)\times (X\times Y)$, $s((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = ((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))$ is a homeomorphism. Thus $$\Delta_{X\times Y} = s\bigl(\Delta_X \times (Y\times Y) \cap (X\times X) \times \Delta_Y\bigr)$$ is closed, hence $X\times Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed, the closed-diagonal characterization is one of the exercises in this section of Munkres.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you don't mind, could you explain why this characterization of Hausdorff sets is useful? Or should I ask that as a separate question?

Comment: It simplifies a number of proofs (please don't ask for a list, over time you will come across a few instances). [The proof that a product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff isn't simpler using it, but I find it nice.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t even think you need to consider the first case in your argument. As long as one of the coordinates differ you are set. Also, a professor might want you to show that $X\times V$ and $X\times V’$ are open. It is true, in fact they are basic open sets.

Comment: I didn't bother showing that $X\times V$ is open because, as you said, it is a basis element for the product topology. This is for self-study, I'm just being a bit pedantic.

Comment: I see what you mean about skipping the first case (where both coordinates differ), though. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Yes! Another clear implication of this is if $X_i$ Is Hausdorff for each $i$ then $\prod^n X_i$ Is Hausdorff for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: By induction, right?